# Header change its position:[fixed] after keyboard popup in Ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I am testing my app on Ipad and the problem what I am facing is that I scroll down on my form and my Top Header bar is `fixed` so it also navigate down as I scroll when I click on `Textbox` then top header bar hide and my sidebar which is `fixed` as same as Header also goes up.SO is there any solution for this problem.I found lot of articles but most of them are kind of hack one which is not good for future prospective so any good solution for this would be great help.

```
.headbar{
 top:0;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%
}

.siderbar {
  top:50px;
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

have u used `position:relative` ?

to use `position:absolute` you must have to keep pos. absolute div inside pos. relative div.

only then position relative and postion fixed works like:

```
    .outerheader_div{
      position:relative;
    }
    .header_fixed{
      position:absolute;
    }

    .outersidebar_div{
      position:relative;
    }
    .sidebar_fixed{
      position:absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is down to how the ipad centers itself around the input.

As the elements are fix they move because they are fixed in that position. You should find that the whole page moves try putting in some lorem ipsum and see if you can replicate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `position:fixed` is the problem. It's quirky in mobile web. See if you can implement a UI using `position:absolute` and `z-index` instead.

Searching: "is position:fixed supported in iOS devices" will give you a lot of resources on the subject, if you indeed have to use `fixed`

Comment: So how can I use `position:absolute` and `z-index` as I facing issues with `fixed` as it goes above when I scroll down mean it's not support the same feature which `fixed` does

Comment: One way would be to 'absolute position' a header container, and put a vertical scroll on the content you want scrollable. I see from another comment here that you are using javascript. Take a look at iScroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). It maybe what you need for the mobile side of your project.

Comment: Yeah I want this app for desktop and Ipad is there any better than Iscoll as I used it and found lot of issue with my App

Comment: Not that I've found (not that I'm a poster-boy for iScroll either). I've only used it in responsive designs -- disabling it in desktop environments

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give an answer without a bit more information.

Are you using JQuery on the page? If so, you could try adding 
    **`data-tap-toggle="false"`**
to the header div.

Also in the css, you should specify **`left:0;`** for fixed elements

Comment: Yeah I am using Jquery not MobileJquery...yeah I also used left:0

Comment: basically the problem is Regarding Position:Fixed

Answer (score 0):

This works on iOS6, but unfortunately not for iOS7: http://jsbin.com/wayurebu/1

The code works for a fixed header, but not a fixed footer. The combination of changing documentElement.className and toggling a fixed positioned element to visible forces the rendering engine to recalculate the fixed viewport, and reposition all fixed elements.

The 500ms timer is needed because sometimes when touch scrolling, the scroll event seems to misfire.

```
<style>
#fix1, #fix2 { display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: 2;}
.head1 #fix1, .head2 #fix2 { display: block; }
</style>
<div id=fix1></div>
<div id=fix2></div>
<script>
var toggleTimer;
var headerToggle = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    function toggle() {
        var toggleit = !(headerToggle++ % 2);
        $(document.documentElement).toggleClass('head1', toggleit);
        $(document.documentElement).toggleClass('head2', !toggleit);
    }
    toggle();
    clearTimeout(toggleTimer);
    toggleTimer = setTimeout(toggle, 500);
});
</script>
```